# Would relocating css styles inline decrease render time for my apps pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, rendering

In my rails(3.1.1) app i have pages that render a lot of data and information, currently i takes roughly 720ms-1480ms(i suspect it will be larger in the future) to render the whole page, there is also quite a bit of css that i use as well. I need to reduce the render time significantly.

Could i decrease the render time if i take out all the styles from the css file and put them inline?
Would this decrease in time have a substantial impact on rendering out pages?
What could i do to reduce render time of the pages?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure all the HTML/CSS/JS code is 100% downloaded and ready to be rendered *before* the 720ms-1480ms starts? Does it really take that long *just to render*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline css will not improve your page rendering speed. Infact it will hamper, since css file will not be cached.

You can do many things to improve page rendering speed, like

1: Compressing js and css files. rails 3.1 assests pipeline automatically does this.
2: caching js and css file
 and much more.

Use a tool like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) to analyse the issues and follow its suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the CSS as a separate file, it will (and should) be cached and in the long run will be faster than inline styles (when viewing other pages that use those styles).